# Modelling a radiofrequency pulse

Tags: radio-frequency, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I'm looking into NMR at the moment and am trying to work out a way of modelling the action of a radiofrequency pulse on nuclear spins. Specifically, if I apply a pulse to rotate the spin by $\pi/2$ I should see this happening correctly if the pulse is resonant at the exact frequency of the nucleus. I would like to be able to model what happens if the resonant frequency of the radiofrequency pulse is not perfectly matched to the nuclear frequency, but the pulse is broad enough that the nucleus still feels some effect from it. Does anyone have any intuition as to how I could go about modelling this?

Answer (score 0):

The Hamiltonian of a spin under a short on-resonant pulse (let's say x-pulse of intensity $b_1$)  just looks like $H = b_1 I_x$ because the on-resonance-ness cancels the nutation term.  Off resonance, it looks like $H = b_1 I_x + \omega_{\text{offset}} I_z$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know how I would go about calculating $\omega_{offset}$?

Comment: "resonant frequency of the radiofrequency pulse is not perfectly matched to the nuclear frequency"   --- $\omega_\text{offset}$ would be your "not perfectly matched".  In an actual experiment, it will be some distribution due to imperfect $B_0$ field, but for many purposes (you didn't say what you're trying to do) that can be neglected.

Comment: Is there a way of taking the shape of the pulse into account?

Comment: Break the shaped pulse $p(t)$ down into a sequence of constant pulses of varying amplitude and phase -- $p(t)$ can be complex -- $p_i$, then you have $H_i = b_{1xi}I_x + b_{1yi}I_y + \omega_\text{offset}I_z$ where $b_{1xi} = real(p_i), b_{1yi} = imag(p_i)$